# how to disable simple_form validation in rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

could one kindly advise me how to disable simple form validation in rails 7.
i am unable to remove the validation. it always states `must exist` no matter which way i use to remove the validation. Thank you for the advise in advance.

i have tried all the below:

```
required: false

html: { required: false }

html: { novalidate: true }

novalidate: true

simple_form_for(resource, html: { novalidate: true }) do

validates :category_addresstitle, presence: false

validates :category_addresstitle_id, presence: false
```

this is an association:

```
Address.rb
belongs_to :category_addresstitle

CategoryAddresstitle.rb
has_many :addresses 

address/form.html.erb
<%= f.association :category_addresstitle, collection: CategoryAddresstitle.all.order(:name), prompt: "Please Select", label: false %>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the association optional.

```
belongs_to :category_addresstitle, optional: true
```